# snowflake pulling a field of list

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am pulling data using snowflake.

1. one of the columns has lists in it. A cell from it appears as `[\n 1792,\n 512,\n 192\n]`. How could I convert it to `[1792,512,192]`? I tried  `REPLACE(field,'\n','')` but it just replaces `\n`
2. I am creating a field like below. How to put a condition in the `where` clause saying that dont pull rows `where groups='other'`

   ```
    CASE
        WHEN groups='x1' THEN 'c'
        WHEN groups='x2' THEN 'r'
        ELSE 'other'
    END AS groups,
   ```

Comment: it more normal to ask one question per question, as "that is what a question" is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex replacement to remove all whitespace characters:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\\s+', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable
WHERE groups IN ('x1', 'x2');
```

Comment: any thoughts about the second question?

Comment: Yes, use: `WHERE groups IN ('x1', 'x2')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use REGEXP_REPALCE to remove all both newlines and spaces:

```
WITH data(cell, groups) as (
    select * from values
    ('[\n 1792,\n 512,\n 192\n]','x1'),
    ('[\n 1792,\n 512,\n 192\n]','x2'),
    ('[\n 1792,\n 512,\n 192\n]','x3')
)
select *
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(cell, '[\\s\\n]+','') as replaced
    ,CASE
         WHEN groups='x1' THEN 'c'
         WHEN groups='x2' THEN 'r'
         ELSE 'other'
     END AS groups
from data
```

[image]

with the input having new lines and spaces:
[image]

and the output being striped:
[image]

in some situations you could use QUALIFY to filter, but here the SQL compiler see nothing speical to bother use it, so blocks it, but also I have two `groups` columns.

But because your input is also your alias, you have polluted the name space.

One method is to use a rename:

```
select * RENAME out_groups as groups 
from
(
    select cell as in_cell
        ,groups as in_groups
        ,REGEXP_REPLACE(cell, '[\\s\\n]+','') as replaced
        ,CASE
             WHEN groups='x1' THEN 'c'
             WHEN groups='x2' THEN 'r'
             ELSE 'other'
         END AS out_groups
    from data
    WHERE out_groups = 'other'
)
```

which would allow a WHERE in at ether layer (inner/outer), or just to use a sub-select without the rename.

```
select * from
(
    select 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(cell, '[\\s\\n]+','') as replaced
        ,CASE
             WHEN groups='x1' THEN 'c'
             WHEN groups='x2' THEN 'r'
             ELSE 'other'
         END AS groups
    from data 
)
WHERE groups = 'other'
```

[image]